# How to determine if variables are set in an array where dependencies exist

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of data which, amongst other elements, contains a start date field, an end date field and a duration field.  During validation I need to check that at least two of them are set, as you can infer the third from the two you have.  Currently my if clause is as follows:

```
if ((!isset($data['start']) && !isset($data['duration'])) 
    || (!isset($data['start']) && !isset($data['end']))
    || (!isset($data['end']) && !isset($data['duration']))
```

It works fine, but my question is whether there is a more elegant way of addressing this issue?

The esoteric part of me is also interested as to whether there could be a function that given n fields and x minimum required would provide a valid/invalid state?  And further to that whether given n fields and a set of relationships between those fields could determine whether the dependencies have been fulfilled?

This array contains many other elements that pertain to the other form fields and so unfortunately merely counting the number of elements is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$ctr = 0;

$ctr += (isset($data['start'])) ? 1 : 0;
$ctr += (isset($data['end'])) ? 1 : 0;
$ctr += (isset($data['duration'])) ? 1 : 0;

if ($ctr >= 2)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

A function per your request, though you need to seed it:

```
$fields = array('start', 'end', 'duration');
$minimum = 2;

function check_fields($data, $fields, $minimum)
{
    $ctr = 0;

    foreach ($fields as $field)
    {
        $ctr += (isset($data[$field])) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return ($ctr >= $minimum) ? true : false;
}

if (check_fields())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is one of those "clever" solutions that will make anyone reading the code (including yourself a couple of weeks from now) woder what the hell is going on here.

Comment: @lafor You could comment the code and eliminate that possibility. ;)

Comment: I feel like this could be a good solution if wrapped up in a function which would take in an array of data, an array of fields to check and a minimum number of fields to be present, loop through the fields to check applying the counter system as above and then returning true/false as to whether it met the minimum number.